# Google DialogFlow (API.AI) - Slot Filling answers only fire 2 times, then exit, and do not cycle through phrases

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

I have an intent with a simple slot filling question, which gathers a Number-Sequence of 4 characters long.

It looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problems are as follows:

1. There are 3 different phrases defined under the slot filling list.  (3rd image above).  However, only the first one is prompted twice in a row by the system.
2. After the phrase is prompted twice, the system exits.  I expect it to keep prompting the 3 different phrases round-robin style, until the user gets it right.

Is the maximum number of attempts specified somewhere?  Can it be changed?

Can we make it use all of the slot-filling phrases, instead of just the first one?

Comment: I'm having the same problem of exiting bot after 3rd try! Have you found any solution? Or at least can I specify my own message before it exit? currently it shows "Sorry, I can't help" and exit the bot

Answer (score 1):

First thing, if you say your verification code is 4-digit long, you should train your agent for 4-digit code only, I can see it in the first snap that you've trained it for 1-digit code only.

Anyways, now coming to your first question, The number of prompts that you have defined here are variations of each other. Api.ai will randomly select any one of them & send it as a response to the user. You do not have a choice to tell the system which one to be prompted first & which one to be second one neither you can define the cycle of prompts like round-robin.

Now, Answer to your second question, I have tried the same set-up at my end. It keeps on prompting unless & until it receives the correct code. Please check snaps. so, there is no limitation to the number of attempts you can have.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not entirely correct.  In my test results:  a placeholder value of "1" - accepts a number sequence of any length, not just 1 in length.   This is something I just discovered.  However, a placeholder of "1234", accepts only 4 digit number-sequences.  If I say 123, or 12345, it doesn't even understand it,  going to the default fallback.

Comment: @Alex Your snap says, you have created your own entity `@VerificationCode` & did not use built-in entity `@sys.number-sequence`. For a new issue, please consider creating a separate question. The answer that is written above purely answers the question asked.